# Como plotar múltiplas linhas verticais entre cada dado (valor) e a média (linha horizontal) em uma série de dados?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Considerando um conjunto de dados plotados no gráfico, como eu posso adicionar linhas verticais conectando o valor do dado e a linha média da amostra?

```
my_data <- c(10,8,13,9,11,5)
plot(my_data, ylim = c(2,16)) + abline(h = mean(my_data))
```

Algo que fique parecido com este exemplo gráfico de outros dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apesar de já haver uma [resposta aceite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/532800/82237), a pergunta também tem o tag `ggplot2`.

```
library(ggplot2)

# Criar a base
my_data <- c(10,8,13,9,11,5)
dados <- data.frame(x = seq_along(my_data), my_data)
#rm(my_data)

# Gráfico
ggplot(dados, aes(x = x, y = my_data)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = x, xend = x, y = mean(my_data), yend = my_data)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(my_data)), linetype = "dashed") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5):

Aqui vai uma solução em base R usando a função `segments()`:

```
my_data <- c(10,8,13,9,11,5)

my_mean <- mean(my_data)
n <- length(my_data)

plot(my_data, pch = 19, cex = 1.5)
abline(h = my_mean, lty = 2, lwd = 1.5)
segments(x0 = 1:n, x1 = 1:n, y0 = my_data, y1 = my_mean, lwd = 2)
```